# Getting Globally declared variable value from 1 function to another function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a very common question about javascript
i have a globally declared variable but how can a function with that variable pass the value in the globally declared variable then use it in the second function??

```
 var ID;

    function test() {

       $.getJSON('/Test1/GetTestID', function (test) {
                $.each(test, function () {
         ID = this["ID"]
         alert(ID);
    }
    })
    }

    function test1() {
             $.getJSON("/TestSite?Test=" + ID; )
    }

    alert(ID);
    test();
    test1();
```

Function test alert the ID but when i declare it Globally it was undeclared.

Can someone help me with this??

Thanks

Comment: `ID = this["ID"]`?? What are you trying to do?

Comment: @RC. actually the id came from  getJson , now added something ..

Comment: you can't, you have to call `test1` in the callback of getJSON

Comment: @RC. so its impossible to pass value on the globally declared variable and fetch it in another Function??

Comment: You forgot the semicolon on `ID = this["ID"]`

Comment: When you declare a variable in global context like this, it gets added to the `window` object. So you'd call it like `window.ID` in different methods. However, you should consider an implementation that doesn't involve a global variable, like suggested in the answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are expecting `getJSON` to be synchronous, but it is not. If the calls are dependent you should nest them:

```
function test() {
       $.getJSON('/Test1/GetTestID', function (test) {
           $.each(test, function () {
              ID = this["ID"]
              $.getJSON("/TestSite?Test=" + ID; )
           })
       })
}
```

`test1` is being called before `test` has completed its `getJSON` call

Answer (score 0):

Because `getJSON` **is asynchronous**, the proper way do perform what you need is to use the returned ID in the callback of `getJSON`:

```
function test() {    
    $.getJSON('/Test1/GetTestID', function (test) {
        $.each(test, function () {
            var theId = this["ID"];
            alert(theId);
            test1(theId);
        }
    });
}

function test1(id) {
    $.getJSON("/TestSite?Test=" + id);
}

test();
```

Comment: sir the `function test1(id)` or `function test1(theId)`?

Comment: @RenTao some basic tutorial about JS variable scope and function might be a good idea

Comment: just clarifying things sir

Comment: In `test()` if `theId` is `123` then `test1(theId)` call `test1` with the value `123` and **in `test1`** we get `123` as value for `id`. `theId` only exists in `test()` and `id` only exists in `test1`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this first you set you id to Zero

```
    var ID =0;
```